# JQuery.live() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know `live` was deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in 1.9 and its is not recommended anymore. But still, as I am preparing for interview machine test and hence I am trying to get difference between `live` and `on`. [Document](https://api.jquery.com/live/) says

> Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event  handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached  lower in the
>   document; the event has already propagated to document.

hence I tried this.
Markup:

```
<div>
    <h1>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('span').live("click",function () {
            alert('span');
        });
        $('a').click(function () {
            alert('span a');
        });
        $('h1').click(function () {
            alert('span a h1');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('div').click(function () {
            alert('span a h1 div');
        });
    });
```

I am using Jquery version 1.7, in which both `live` and `on` exist.

Whats happening:

1. `live` of span is not getting called, instead it calls directly `click` of `a`.
2. If I remove all other events than `live` then it is getting called.
3. As doc says, it is doing exactly opposite, i.e it's stopping event bubbling if I use `event.stopPropagation();`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3bbprqu/)

Comment: `Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event 
handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached 
lower in the document;` the behaviour in jsfiddle is proper. It's stopping the event from bubbling up the document, but it's inefficient in stopping the events attached to the child dom that's why events on h1 and a has fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers attached by `live` are attached always to the `document`. If you call `event.stopPropagation` in a callback of `live` then this event is already bubbled up to the document, so it will have no effect to directly attached event handlers.

Your `event.stopPropagation()` is called when the event reaches, the `h1`element, so it will never reach the `document` where the `live` event handler is attached.

With `on` you can create all type of event handling jQuery supports. If you look at the source of jQuery, you can see that in 1.7 the `live` function just maps to on:

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
   jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
   return this;
}
```

The reason for `live` to be removed was to make the api clearer and more logical to when event happens and where they are catched.

**EDIT**

Your DOM and the place where your event handlers are attached to:

```
 document    $('span').live("click") **not called**  (equal to: $(document).on('click', 'span') ) 
    |
   div       $('div').click() **not called**
    |
    h1       $('h1').click() + event.stopPropagation() **the propagation (bubbling)  is stopped here not reaching the document**
    |
    a        $('a').click()
    |
   span      **event happens here and bubbles up**
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but what about first point? why span`live` is not getting called?

Comment: @Imad Sorry the `About 3.` should have been removed. This is related to all three. The `live` callbacks will always be the last callbacks that are called for the given event, because they are attached to the `document` which is the last element in the bubbling phase

Comment: Sorry sir, but I can't find answer to point 1 in this, may be I misunderstood complete concept.

Comment: @Imad I added an edit to the answer visualizing what I have written.